# How do I import from a child directory / subfolder?

Tags: python

From main.py, I want to import a file from the backend folder

WebAppName/main.py
WebAppName/backend/handlers.py

How do I specify this as an import statement

I am aware that importing from the same folder is just import handlers

But this is a child directory, so how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do an import, Python searchs for whatever you are importing in the directories listed in sys.path, which is a Python list.  To make a module or other code source importable, simply append the path to the code source to sys.path:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'backend'))
```

After that line, then do your import of handlers and it will work.

good luck,
Mike

Comment: Yes. __init__ is for dealing with packages.  If you are working out of a package, then the other answers are the way to go. But it's not clear to me that you have a package.  It think this will work for you.

Comment: Ok. Thank you Mike Who Hunts.

Comment: Mike Who Hunts! I like that!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an `__init__.py` file in the `backend` folder for Python to consider it a *package*. Then you can do `import backend.handlers` or `from backend.handlers import foo`

Comment: Does anything need to be in the __init__file or can it be blank?

Comment: `__init__.py` can be blank file.

Answer (score 1):

so you are importing handlers.py in main.py?

`import backend.handlers as handlers`

should work if you put an `__init__.py` in backend

EDIT: option 2

in the beginning of main.py you could add the child folder to your python path by doing something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./backend')
```

Comment: Does this solution work without using a package ass the person above states?

Comment: first solution needs `__init__.py`, I've added a second solution by adding a path

Comment: or actually see MikeHunter's path solution